# how to give database path for sqlite using swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

I tried below code to create database, but this returns me thread break point error during run time, near 
`let part1DbPath = "/Users/username/Documents/"`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let part1DbPath = "/Users/username/Documents/"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func openDatabase() -> COpaquePointer {
        var db: COpaquePointer = nil
        if sqlite3_open_v2(part1DbPath, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE  | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, "") == SQLITE_OK {
            print("Successfully opened connection to database at \(part1DbPath)")
        return db
        } else {
            print("Unable to open database. Verify that you created the directory described " +
            "in the Getting Started section.")   
      }
    return db
    }
}
```

It looks like I am going wrong in declaring path for database. What's wrong in this ? How do I make it work ? Thanks for any help

[image]

Comment: where are you running application? simulator or real device?

Comment: @LucaDavanzo I am using simulator

Comment: Read answer below, you simply setted up a breakpoint, don't worry!

Comment: @LucaDavanzo ok got it. what should be the path to create sqlite db in simulator / real device ? Is the path that I've given is correct ?

Comment: Try this: let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
        NSLog("Document Path: %@", documentsPath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set breakpoints in your code that will halt the execution. This is not an error, but used to inspect your code while it is running. This is called "debugging" and is very useful.

You can either remove the breakpoint by clicking the blue marker on the left side of the line, or you can choose to continue the execution using the Debug view (press the "Play" button).

If the debug view is not open, it can be opened by pressing the small arrow in the bottom of the view.